# Nuxt-calendly remove cookie setting option

Tags: vue.js, calendly

I want to remove the `Cookie Settings` option in my calendly popup text integration but the option `hideGdprBanner` does not work.
[image]

does anyone have an idea how to remove it? or if it can be removed at all? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by adding this to your Calendly URL `?hide_gdpr_banner=1`

https://yourdomain.com/endpoint/30min?hide_gdpr_banner=1

https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/4418236309399-Calendly-cookie-management-and-banner#h_01FRRNAC7XQRSYDC1MVST35G5E

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34812574)